# fetch custom shared Group or User Ids in after trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, sharing

I have Custom Sharing rule

In After Insert trigger. I don't get public group Ids or User ids shared through custom sharing rule.

```
List<Objcet__Share> sharedUsers = [select Id, ParentId, AccessLevel, UserOrGroupId, RowCause from Objcet__Share where parentId = recordId];
```

This list returns only one record that is the owner of the record but actually, two groups are assigned to this through custom sharing.

Answer (score 1):

As per [this guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm). sharing rule will be execute after trigger. try separate the transaction with @future . Try run the same in developer console and check whether actual two groups are assigned.